# $R$-module $M$ as a special map $R\otimes M\rightarrow M$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

I think an $R$-module $M$ is an abelian group $M$ along with a bilinear action of the ring $R$ on it. By the universal property of the tensor product of abelian groups, the bilinear action can be replaced by a map $R\otimes M\rightarrow M$ satisfying the analogues of $s(rm)=(sr)m$ and $1m=m$.

What are these analogues? (i.e how do I write them down?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f\colon R\otimes M\to M$ be the map. The analogues are:

- $f(s\otimes f(r\otimes m)) = f(sr\otimes m)$
- $f(1\otimes m) = m$

Comment: I guess that's really all there is to it. Thanks

Comment: Yes, my fault, was a bit quick.

Comment: Is there perhaps a way to encode this into some commutative square?

Comment: I guess you'd have to do some work to make this precise, but you could do this: First, let $g\colon R\otimes R\to R$ be the map $g(s\otimes r) = sr$. Then the composition $R\otimes R\otimes M\to R\otimes M\to M$ given by first applying $f$ to the last two factors, and then applying $f$ to the result, would have to agree with the composition $R\otimes R\otimes M\to R\otimes M\to M$ given by applying $g$ in the first two factors and then applying $f$. I'm not sure how to draw a commutative diagram on this website though!